# Python MKL_THREADING_LAYER=INTEL is incompatible with libgomp.so.1 library

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

```
!mkdir -p '{FRAME_OUTPUT_DIR}'
%cd /home/jovyan/project/DAIN

!MKL_THREADING_LAYER=AMD

!python -W ignore colab_interpolate.py --netName DAIN_slowmotion --time_step {fps/TARGET_FPS} --start_frame 1 --end_frame {frame_count} --frame_input_dir '{FRAME_INPUT_DIR}' --frame_output_dir '{FRAME_OUTPUT_DIR}'
```

outputs this...

I have tried setting FORCE to 1 but nothing happens, outputs then its gone...

````
/home/jovyan/project/DAIN
Error: mkl-service + Intel(R) MKL: MKL_THREADING_LAYER=INTEL is incompatible with libgomp.so.1 library.
    Try to import numpy first or set the threading layer accordingly. Set MKL_SERVICE_FORCE_INTEL to force it.```

Hey there, can anyone help me solve this problem with DAIN? I'm using Saturn Cloud with pytorch but it outputs this...
````

Answer (score 4):

Try to reinstall numpy. It helps me.

```
pip install -U numpy
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this link](https://code-aster.org/forum2/viewtopic.php?id=25998) you can fix it by running this command (If you have linux):

```
export MKL_SERVICE_FORCE_INTEL=1
```

Then restart your script.